# How is a Windows Active Directory Machine Account Password stored in Windows/Samba Clients?

Tags: passwords, windows, active-directory, kerberos

It's said that a `Windows Machine Account Password` is usually composed of 120 characters in UTF-16-LE format. But when looking at the value stored in the Windows Registry under `HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\$MACHINE.ACC\CurrVal` one finds a somewhat random length blob of binary data which is way more than the 240 bytes expected and also doesn't seem to be UTF-16 anymore. I saw lengths of 332, 356, 358 and 382 bytes.

What explains this difference? What is going on?
How is the value stored in `CurrVal` actually put together?

Some background: I try to use a company Wifi which wants me to present this value for authentication. I wrote a small script to extract the value from Samba's `/var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb` (which looks very similar to the one in the Windows Registry) and plug it into a NetworkManager WPA2-Enterprise 802.1x PEAP profile which works fine for me for some years. Currently I try to switch to SSSD which only gives me cleartext 120 bytes UTF-8 (by running `adcli update --show-details --show-password`) for the Machine Password and I want to figure out how to transform those 120 characters to the Windows-/Samba-like format I can use to authenticate.

Comment: Welcome to the community. What distro are you using?..

Comment: I did the Samba workflow of `secrets.db` machine password to NetworkManager in Arch Linux and now I try to do something similar in Ubuntu 22.04 but with SSSD and not Samba/Winbind. My Registry knowledge is based on Windows 10.

Comment: I've already grepped my way from [`generate_random_machine_password`](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blame/e7ef43cead4ddab85e96b176c7c9123c28a033d2/lib/util/genrand_util.c#L320) to [`secrets_store_machine_pw_sync`](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/e7ef43cead4ddab85e96b176c7c9123c28a033d2/source3/passdb/machine_account_secrets.c#L442) in the Samba source code but I struggle to understand the important details in [`secrets_store_domain_info`](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/e7ef43cead4ddab85e96b176c7c9123c28a033d2/source3/passdb/machine_account_secrets.c#L847).

Answer (score 0):

A pretty common method is to hash the password (possibly after having added some salt to prevent brute force attacks), which seems to be somewhat supported by the identifiers of the linked source code. Note, that a hashed password contains fully binary byte strings, so any attempt to interpret this as unicode may fail.

Comment: I already thought about that and I think there is a salt like `HOST/example.org` in use. But wouldn't that imply the size should be constant? Like every MD4 hash is 128 bit. So why would the length vary? It also looks like size differs for the same machine when the password is rotated which happens regularly.